# Problem in creating a recurring data

Tags: event, task-recurrence

I want to create a recurring data for next 1 - 4 weeks depending upon the no of weeks entered by the user and according to date entered by the user.

For Example, date entered is 1/05/2018 and the day is Tuesday.

I have seven checkboxes in UI from Monday to Sunday and one number field labeled- No of Weeks.

If I select Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday checkbox and No of Weeks entered is 2 then for next 2 weeks and on the selected days, copy of the record should get created.

My problem is that I am able to create a data for next two weeks but i cannot get the dates for next two week's Monday Tuesday and Wednesday.

Following is my code which i have written:

```
public with sharing class BeatPlanHandler
{
  public void createRecurringPlan(List<Beat_Trip_Planner__c>currentListOfBeatPlan)
  {
   List<Beat_Trip_Planner__c> insertedBeatPlan = new List<Beat_Trip_Planner__c>();
   List<Beat_Trip_Planner__c> newBeatPlan = new List<Beat_Trip_Planner__c>();

   Decimal noOfWeeks;
   Decimal noOfDays;

    for(Beat_Trip_Planner__c bplan : currentListOfBeatPlan)
    {  
       noOfWeeks = bplan.No_of_Weeks__c;
       noOfDays = bplan.No_of_Days__c;
       if(bplan.No_of_Weeks__c != null && bplan.No_of_Days__c != null)
       {
          for(Integer i=1; i<=bplan.No_of_Weeks__c; i++)
             {
                Date d;
                d = bplan.Date__c;
                String day = d.Day();
                System.debug(this is today's day:'+d.Day());


                 if(bplan.Monday__c == true)
                    {
                      Beat_Trip_Planner__c bp = new Beat_Trip_Planner__c();
                      bp.Area__c = bplan.Area__c;
                      bp.City__c = bplan.City__c;
                      bp.Retailer__c = bplan.Retailer__c;
                      bp.Remarks__c = bplan.Remarks__c;
                      bp.Date__c = d.addDays(6);
                      }
                      bp.Month__c = bplan.Month__c;
                      bp.Year__c = bplan.Year__c;

                      newBeatPlan.add(bp);
                    }
                    if(bplan.Tuesday__c == true)
                    {
                      Beat_Trip_Planner__c bp = new Beat_Trip_Planner__c();
                      bp.Area__c = bplan.Area__c;
                      bp.City__c = bplan.City__c;
                      bp.Retailer__c = bplan.Retailer__c;
                      bp.Remarks__c = bplan.Remarks__c;
                      bp.Date__c = d.addDays(7);
                      bp.Month__c = bplan.Month__c;
                      bp.Year__c = bplan.Year__c;

                      newBeatPlan.add(bp);
                    }
                   if(bplan.Wednesday__c == true)
                    { 
                      Beat_Trip_Planner__c bp = new Beat_Trip_Planner__c();
                      bp.Area__c = bplan.Area__c;
                      bp.City__c = bplan.City__c;
                      bp.Retailer__c = bplan.Retailer__c;
                      bp.Remarks__c = bplan.Remarks__c;
                      bp.Date__c = d.addDays(8);
                      bp.Month__c = bplan.Month__c;
                      bp.Year__c = bplan.Year__c;

                      newBeatPlan.add(bp);
                    }
                   if(bplan.Thursday__c == true)
                    { 
                      Beat_Trip_Planner__c bp = new Beat_Trip_Planner__c();
                      bp.Area__c = bplan.Area__c;
                      bp.City__c = bplan.City__c;
                      bp.Retailer__c = bplan.Retailer__c;
                      bp.Remarks__c = bplan.Remarks__c;
                      bp.Date__c = d.addDays(9);
                      bp.Month__c = bplan.Month__c;
                      bp.Year__c = bplan.Year__c;

                      newBeatPlan.add(bp);
                    }
                   if(bplan.Friday__c == true)
                    { 
                      Beat_Trip_Planner__c bp = new Beat_Trip_Planner__c();
                      bp.Area__c = bplan.Area__c;
                      bp.City__c = bplan.City__c;
                      bp.Retailer__c = bplan.Retailer__c;
                      bp.Remarks__c = bplan.Remarks__c;
                      bp.Date__c = d.addDays(10);
                      bp.Month__c = bplan.Month__c;
                      bp.Year__c = bplan.Year__c;

                      newBeatPlan.add(bp);
                    }
                    if(bplan.Saturday__c == true)
                    {
                      Beat_Trip_Planner__c bp = new Beat_Trip_Planner__c();
                      bp.Area__c = bplan.Area__c;
                      bp.City__c = bplan.City__c;
                      bp.Retailer__c = bplan.Retailer__c;
                      bp.Remarks__c = bplan.Remarks__c;
                      bp.Date__c = d.addDays(11);
                      bp.Month__c = bplan.Month__c;
                      bp.Year__c = bplan.Year__c;

                      newBeatPlan.add(bp);
                    }
                    if(bplan.Sunday__c == true)
                    { 
                      Beat_Trip_Planner__c bp = new Beat_Trip_Planner__c();
                      bp.Area__c = bplan.Area__c;
                      bp.City__c = bplan.City__c;
                      bp.Retailer__c = bplan.Retailer__c;
                      bp.Remarks__c = bplan.Remarks__c;
                      bp.Date__c = d.addDays(12);
                      bp.Year__c = bplan.Year__c;

                      newBeatPlan.add(bp);
                    }
             }
       }
       try
       {
          insert newBeatPlan;
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
           {
             System.debug('insertion failed'+ex);
           }
    }

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

One place to start is by removing the code duplication so it is clearer what is going on. Then add a week factor:

```
            for (Integer i = 1; i <= bplan.No_of_Weeks__c; i++) {

                // Day of week offsets
                Integer[] days = new Integer[] {};
                if (bplan.Monday__c) days.add(6);
                if (bplan.Tuesday__c) days.add(7);
                if (bplan.Wednesday__c) days.add(8);
                if (bplan.Thursday__c) days.add(9);
                if (bplan.Friday__c) days.add(10);
                if (bplan.Saturday__c) days.add(11);
                if (bplan.Sunday__c) days.add(12);

                // Week offset
                Integer w = (i - 1) * 7;

                for (Integer d : days) {
                    Beat_Trip_Planner__c bp = bplan.clone();
                    bp.Date__c = bp.Date__c.addDays(w + d);
                    newBeatPlan.add(bp);
                }
            }
```

though I'm not fully clear what you are aiming to do here (e.g. would have expected the days offset for Monday to be a multiple of 7).

Comment: thanks Keith C for replying my aim is to clone the record for no of weeks and for selected days and the days offset for monday is a multiple of 7 only but code u gave didnt create any cloned record sorry!!